# how to "allow" firefox internet security automatically

Tags: python, security, firefox, pywin32

I'm trying to figure out a way to "click" the "Allow" button in firefox internet security window by using pywin32 or windows API. I was able to get the "internet security" window by using FindWindow. I tried to send a button click event but no response and the button looks invisible from spyxx. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to do this? This looks like some security problem to me.

Comment: our group is currently working on the browser ids product and our test page will be blocked by the firefox internet security before our product. if i want to automate this test, i have to solve this problem. Gosh... it will be much better if i can past a picture but my reputation is lower than 10 :(

Answer (score 2):

It's probably not a real Windows button but a XUL widget, so only Firefox knows where it is and what it looks like.

Since your question smells like "I want to write a Trojan", that's as much info I'm willing to give.

[EDIT] Firefox is a very flexible browser, especially when it comes to packaging it. So what you should consider is

1. package the browser with the settings (obviously this only works if the setting is static)
2. Write a FF plugin which allows you to do what you want.

Since I've never done this myself, a rough outline: Write a plugin which gets notified when a page is loaded (look into the source of the [Greasemonkey add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) for an example; maybe Greasemonkey can already do what you need).

Now if the page loaded contains some special code, your plugin modifies the browser settings. Now all you need to do is to package firefox with this plugin for your IDS suite.

Or maybe you can make the plugin

Comment: uh.. what i am trying to write is not a trojan but a test tool for our IDS product. but thanks for your clue.

Comment: In fact, i can prove it by pasting a picture but i need gain my reputation to 10 first :P

Comment: *lol* How do you plan to prove me the picture shows something that actually exists? ;-)